# Query GeoServer WFS layer attributes with form

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, geodjango, django

How can I set up a form in HTML to query the attributes in my GeoServer WFS layer? I assume it has something to do with the action attribute but I'm not sure how it will work. Something like `<form action="http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs *form created GET request here*" method="get">`

Here is a screenshot of the map and form to give you a better idea of what I am trying to accomplish.

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way is to send the form is through JavaScript, something like below,

```js
$("#formElement").on("click", function () {
var wfsLayer = L.Geoserver.wfs("http://localhost:8080/geoserver/wfs", {
  layers: "topp:tasmania_roads",
});
wfsLayer.addTo(map);
});
```